# change background color in p-triStateCheckbox of PrimeNG

Tags: primeng

I've tried changing the Background-color of tristatecheckbox as shown below. The said codes will work if I directly update the CSS in the web console. But when I applied it in my codes. it won't work.

```
.fa-check:before {
     Background-color: green !important;
 }

 .fa-close:before {
     Background-color: red !important;
 }
```

Can anyone, help me with this?

Comment: Your CSS works fine : [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/gPYWIPPkuuHJxh2HWs09?p=preview). There might be another conflict with your CSS or with CSS from an external library.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prepend your CSS with `:host >>>`:

```
:host >>> .fa-check::before {
  background-color: cyan !important;
}

:host >>> .fa-close::before {
  background-color: magenta !important;
}
```

Note that I've changed the colors since green & red are the defaults.

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/fLf5oR?p=preview)